# How to get value of select2:unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

how can I get value of unselected option in [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) using `select2:unselect`

```
$('#mySelect').on("select2:unselect", function(e){

    var unselected_value = $('#mySelect').val(); // using this shows 'null'
    // or using below expression also shows 'null'
    var unselected_value = $('#mySelect :selected').val();

    alert(unselected_value);
}).trigger('change');
```

in above code alert shows 'null'

I need to use `select2:unselect` because 'change' event will sense `:select` and `:unselect` both.

Comment: may help https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2959

Comment: no that is not the case event is being triggered but I'm not able to fetch the value of the unselected option. @Mohamed-Yousef thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I've got the solution and that is: 
The value of unselected option is only available before it is unselected. Not at `select2:unselect` rather at `select2:unselecting`
now the code will be:

```
$('#mySelect').on("select2:unselecting", function(e){
         var unselected_value = $('#mySelect').val();
         alert(unselected_value);
    }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: This will work for a single selection. For removing an item from multiple selections, see gfrobenius's answer above.

Answer (score 16):

This is an older question but maybe this answer will help someone.  I'm using Select2 v4.0.3 with multiple values/tags and need only the ID of specific one being removed.  I really did not want to use the `unselecting` event as mentioned in other answers.  In the `unselect` event there is no `args` object, so you can get to the ID of the one you are trying to remove like this...

```
jQuery('.mySelect2').on("select2:unselecting", function(e){
    return true; // I don't use this unselecting event but here is how you could use it to get the ID of the one you are trying to remove.
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.params);
    console.log(e.params.args.data);
    console.log(e.params.args.data.id);
    //console.log(e.params.args.data.tag); data.tag is specific to my code.
});

jQuery('.mySelect2').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.params);
    console.log(e.params.data);
    console.log(e.params.data.id);
    //console.log(e.params.data.tag); data.tag is specific to my code.

    /*
    Now you can do an ajax call or whatever you want for the specific
    value/tag that you are trying to remove which is: e.params.data.id.
    */
```

Comment: Thank you! Scratched my head for ages. The official docs mention `data` but no mention of `args` at all!

Comment: This is the more complete answer thus upvoting

Answer (score 15):

Actually, the data value is inside the event Object. It would be useful if you are dealing with select2 multiple values.

```
function(e){
    console.log(e.params.data)
}
```

Comment: Specifically, `e.params.data.id` is the `value` of the selected/unselected item and `e.params.data.text` is the `innerText` label.

Comment: Specifically, when the  **`event.type`** is **select2:unselecting** then use `event.params.args.data`, otherwise, you'll get an **undefined**.

Comment: @Jcc.Sanabria Thank you so much! Not sure why `unselecting` has a different parameter structure, and it's still not documented. How did you discover `args` was in there?

Comment: Lol, with some debugging. Pleased to know that I could help you.

Comment: To clarify, this will only work on `select2:unselect`. If you are working with `select2:unselecting`, then you need to access `e.params.args.data.id` instead of `e.params.data.id`

Answer (score 7):

The unselected element is passing through e.params.data. We can access its value using 'id' and if you need the text you can use 'data.text'.

```
 $("select").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
             var value=   e.params.data.id;
             alert(value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the specific option value if you're using multiple tags:

```
var unselected_value = $('#mySelect option:selected').val();
alert(unselected_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to change the background color of a city in a SVG map looking for the name of the specific city. Hope this could help you

```
 $(".js-example-diacritics").on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {
                var element = evt.params.data.element;
                townColor(element.text, unHighLightColor);
            });
```

To the method townColor() I'm passing the text (city name) of the select2 element unselected and constant named unHighLightColor that holds the color name.

Answer (score 0):

on Select2 4.0.3 i'am found `e.params` was changed. So, to find id from unselecting item, change your code like this :

```
$('select').on('select2:unselecting', function (e) {
    var id = e.params.args.data.id; //your id
    alert('Are You Sure ?');
    e.preventDefault();
  // Do something with your id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use $(this).val(), this going to return you the last value marked in the select

```
$('#mySelect').on("select2:unselecting", function(e){
         alert($(this).val());
    })
```

Comment: this shows all selected values. how can i get value of elemnt I just tried to unslect by clicking on cross

Answer (score 0):

> @Mahmaood ali
> Thank you for your solution it worked like a charm for me.

For @Vipin Kr. Singh  problem.

```
  $('#mySelect').on("select2:unselect", function(e){
        var unselected_value = e.params.data.id;
    })
    $('#mySelect').on("select2:select", function(e){
        var selected_value = e.params.data.id;
    })
```

This way only you can get only one selected or unselected value at a time.