# Select2 obtaining removed value from multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using a theme which has got select2 version 3.4.3. I want to obtain the removed value ID, so I tried with:

```
$('#mymultiple').on("select2:removed", function (e) {
    console.log(e.val);
})
```

But it does not detect the event. Then, I tested:

```
$('#mymultiple').on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
    console.log(e.val);
})
```

But it gives me an undefined value, although the object has some info:

```
$('#mymultiple').on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

> Object { type: "select2:unselect", params: Object, timeStamp:
>   1473273802173, jQuery18308796073916839738: true, isTrigger: true,
>   exclusive: undefined, namespace: "", namespace_re: null, result:
>   undefined, target: , ...}

I have to use this version because I need to use the styles given by the template project (I test 3.5.3 and `removed` works ok, but I can not import the styles correctly). So how can I get the removed value from the multiple select?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030983/16462707
Please see this answer, it should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like select2 ver 3.4.3 doesn't have support for the removed elements event.

You can use this workaround instead:

> note that my code support removing of multiple elements (which I'm not sure select2 support, but you have it just in case)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#s1").select2();
  $("#s1").data('originalvalues', []);
  $("#s1").on('change', function(e) {
    var that = this;
    removed = []
    
    $($(this).data('originalvalues')).each(function(k, v) {
      if (!$(that).val()) {
        removed[removed.length] = v;
        return false;
      }
      if ($(that).val().indexOf(v) == -1) {
        removed[removed.length] = v;
      }
    });
    
    
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $(this).data('originalvalues', $(this).val());
    } else {
      $(this).data('originalvalues', []);
    }
    
    console.log("Removed: " + removed)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/select2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="s1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am having the same issue with added values, how would you lead with this? I figured out but in a complex way (take originvales and make a diff with $(this).val() and put the difference in a variable when $(this).val() length is bigger)

Comment: Well, I think that @smcd should get the accepted answer here. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

The event in 3.4.3 is "removed" instead of "select2:removed"

(found it by looking through [select2 v3.4.3 source code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/select2.js))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mymultiple').select2({
    placeholder: 'pick items'
  });

  $('#mymultiple').on("removed", function(e) {
    alert(e.val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.3/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id='mymultiple' multiple>
  <option value='one'>One</option>
  <option value='two'>Two</option>
  <option value='three'>Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're here and needed to store a list of all removed items ever since the page loaded, you can use my code here... it adds a hidden-input for each removed item so it is sent as an array in the request...

```
    var originalItems = $('#resources-select').val();
    $('#resources-select').on("change", function(e) {
        var selected = $('#resources-select').val();
        $("#removed-resources").html("");
        $.each(originalItems, function(index, value) {
            if($.inArray(value, selected) < 0) {
                $("#removed-resources").append("<input type='hidden' name='removed-resources[]' value='"+value+"'></input>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Just make sure you have a div inside the form where the hidden-inputs will be appended...

```
<div id="removed-resources"></div>
<select name="resources[]" id="resources-select" multiple="multiple">
   ...
</select>
```